# What does かとか mean in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, usage, quotes

血筋かとか言われたくなかったんでな.

I've been watching some anime and came across this sentence and while i understand what it means i can't understand the (かとか）part.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/41850/9831

Answer (score 1, accepted):

血筋か  とか  言われたくなかった  んでな.

とか : among other things; such things as; or something like that.

Perhaps it is more easier to understand it by yourself in this way.